# Android Studio sees device in one project but not another

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

My Samsung A70 Android device is visible in one project, but it isn't visible in another project in Android studio.

[Device visible in first project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HraBm.png)

[Device not visible in second project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpvkh.png)

I've tried many things such as reinstalling the driver, updating the driver, and restarting my computer. Nothing seems to work. I created a new project and it doesn't see my device either; but whenever I open the first project, the device is visible. Also, if it's important, the projects are all flutter projects.

**What do you think could be causing this? What can I do to fix it?**

Comment: What are the minimum android versions required by both apps? The app where the device is not visible may have its minimum sdk higher than the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works now. When I ran flutter doctor, it reported that no devices are connected even though my phone was connected. The flutter doctor also displayed the following:

```
[x] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
      Unable to locate Android SDK
```

So, I wrote the following:

```
flutter config --android-sdk C:\Android\Sdk
```

and

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

After which the flutter doctor showed that my device was connected.
Android Studio is now able to see my device.